# Error while compiling gosqlite on windows

Tags: sqlite, go

I tried to build gosqlite in order to get my project running under windows.
Unfortunately cgo throws an error while calling gcc.
I broke it down to this:

```
$ ../../../../../pkg/tool/windows_386/cgo.exe sqlite.go
fork/exec C:\cygwin\bin\gcc.exe: error 5 (FormatMessage failed with err=15100)
```

I researched the errorcode and got this:
System error code 15100 means "The resource loader failed to find MUI file." This error code may also display as "ERROR_MUI_FILE_NOT_FOUND" or as the value 0x3AFC.
[source](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/findbyerrormessage/tp/system_error_codes_15100_15199.htm)

My environment is an fresh win7 virtualbox install with cygwin, go1, sqlite3.

I hope for help, it's my third day, I'm trying to solve this ...

with kind regards!

Comment: I don't have a definitive answer but consider the first comment on the FormatMessage MSDN page: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679351(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Have you considered trying MinGW?  I'm using sqlite3 in a Go program on Win 7 with MinGW and it works swimmingly...

Answer (score 1):

The error message you got out of cgo is not very good:

fork/exec C:\cygwin\bin\gcc.exe: error 5 ...

error 5 is ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED. I suspect, cgo tried to run gcc and CreateProcess failed with ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED.

You should have received proper error message, but Go could not translate "error 5" into message string. It is looking for "English" message:

http://code.google.com/p/go/source/browse/src/pkg/syscall/syscall_windows.go#82

but, I suspect, you computer do not have these. If that is the case, then Go should fall back to "native" message instead.

If you create an issue about your bad error message here http://code.google.com/p/go/issues/list, maybe something will get done.

Alex